# C# - Checking For Device Problems and System Problems

Tags: c#, powershell, system, device

In C#, How Could I go about checking for device and systems errors? Would it be simple to use PowerShell Scipts, or would that add to the complexity and difficulty?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "device and system errors"?  Which devices and systems?

Comment: No Specific Errors, Just errors in general. Maybe detect the possible causes a device might be failing. I can do this manually, but It is for other users, so to make life a bit easier, maybe detecting some possible causes and displaying them for the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Windows 7 clients check out the [Windows Troubleshooting Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323778(VS.85).aspx).  Here is a [download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=48c2fc09-c3e0-4188-8f4f-216e0c25df1d#tm) on it with more details. It uses PowerShell scripts to do exacty what you're talking about.  This [blog post](http://www.withinwindows.com/2009/01/12/crash-course-on-authoring-windows-7-troubleshooting-packs/) shows how to author a troubleshooting pack - it's pretty easy.

I don't think WTP works on downlevel platforms.  In this case, I would just write some PowerShell scripts to detect and fix root causes.  If you want to wrap that up in a nice UI, check out [PowerBoots](http://huddledmasses.org/powerboots/) - an easy way to create a WPF GUI on top of your script.  If you want to host PowerShell in your on C#-based GUI it is very simple.  Here's a code snippet from a Forms app:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cmd = @"Get-ChildItem $home\Documents -recurse | " +
                      "Where {!$_.PSIsContainer -and " +
                      "($_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7))} | " +
                      "Sort Fullname | Foreach {$_.Fullname}";

        using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runspace.Open();
            using (Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline(cmd))
            {
                this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;

                pipeline.Commands.AddScript(cmd);
                Collection<PSObject> results = pipeline.Invoke();
                foreach (PSObject obj in results)
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(obj);
                }

                this.Cursor = Cursors.Default;
            }
        }
    }
```

You need to add a reference to the System.Management.Automation assembly.  If you have installed the Windows/.NET SDK that should be in ProgramFiles\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0.  You will also need a couple of using statememets:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
```

Comment: I would love to get some of the Powershell in my GUI. Where can I contact you at?